# OpenId Connect Identity Provider initiated backchannel logout not working

Tags: spring-security, amazon-cognito, logout, openid-connect, pac4j

I'm working on a java **Spring Boot** project that manages users and sessions internally. It relies on OIDC, AWS Cognito being the Identity Provider, for sign-in and, I would hope, **sign-out** of the users.
What I understand from the [OIDC Spec for backchannel logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) is that:

1. I must provide an endpoint for logout in my backend application. I am using **Pac4J** as my OIDC library in a java Spring Boot application, and have enabled the `logout` endpoint as per the [Pac4J Spring Security documentation](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j/wiki/Logout-configuration)
2. The Identity Provider **AWS Cognito** should send a request to the logout endpoint if the user is signed out from the Identity Provider
3. When I receive a valid call (as per the OIDC spec) on this endpoint, I **must** destroy the user's session with my application.

However, the user being logged out of the Identity Provider (AWS Cognito) does not seem to result in a call to the logout endpoint of my application.

I am unable to find documentation for this backchannel behaviour in the AWS Cognito docs.

1. Have I understood the backchannel logout correctly?
2. Is this currently unsupported as OIDC logout is still (as of **March 12, 2019**) in draft status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the main developer of Pac4J who was very prompt to reply.

**AWS Cognito:**

- Currently does not seem to support backchannel logout

**Pac4J:**

- Backchannel logout is currently not supported by the library for OIDC, and it isn't on the roadmap either: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pac4j-users/SD_IgKVZWvM, the /logout referenced in the documentation is for internal (to the app) logout + (if configured) forwarding a logout request to the identity provider. It is NOT a OIDC-backchannel-logout endpoint.

Comment: I do not know AWS Cognito but same exist in Google OIDC provider and I think it is up to developer how to implement sign-out. As a delegating authentication provider the OIDC authenticates user but its our app's responsibility to create a session and persist authentication state. Although we can use revocation endpoint in google to make access token invalid.